# /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, cron

I created a new task in crontab as shown below :

```
*/2 * * * *       mongodump --db prodys --out /backup/databases/mongoDatabases/`date +"%m-%d-%y"`
```

I'm getting following error :

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
```

Please help, I don't have any clue whats wrong.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem is that `cron` treats `%` as newlines. From `crontab POSIX man` page:

> Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash \, 
>   will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first %  will  be
>   sent to the command as standard input.

Also use [Command Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) syntax as `$()` over the legacy `` syntax as

You could change your command to something like,

```
*/2 * * * *       mongodump --db prodys --out /backup/databases/mongoDatabases/$(date +'\%m-\%d-\%y')
```